# Trying to implement a change() event on a DOM Element through the module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, events

I have a checkbox and when the user clicks on it I want it to change the private variable `output`. then I want to update an object's property to the output. In the code below I can't get the change event to work I believe it's because I don't know how to interact with DOM elements through the Module pattern. so if you can help with that it would be great.

Something else that concerns me is that I want the price variable in the `apple` object to be updated when ever the user click. the price will change values to a random number every time the user clicks the checkbox. I always have a problem updating an object outside of a change event like you will see in my code. `apple.price` is outside change event. If you could me with that would be gratefully appreciated too.

```
var CreatItems = function(name, price, pic){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.pic = pic;
}
CreatItems.prototype.listOut = function(){
    console.log(this.name + this.price + this.pic)
}

var changingPrice = (function(){
    // testMethod : function(){
    //  return 1.77
    // }
    var output;
    var testMethod = function(){
        return output
    }
    var clickedWithOnes = function(){
        $("#withones").change(function(){
            if(this.checked){
                // output = "checked";
                console.log("Checked")
            }else{
                // output = "unchecked";
                console.log("unchecked")
            }
        })
    }
    return{
        testMethod : testMethod,
        clickedWithOnes : clickedWithOnes
    }
})()
changingPrice.clickedWithOnes()
var price = changingPrice.testMethod()
// console.log(price)
var apple = new CreatItems("apple", price, "will be red div")
console.log(apple.price)
```

I get consoled "undefined"

Comment: Do you ever see the "Checked" or "unchecked" messages to the console? It's not surprising that price is always `undefined` -- it comes from `testMethod`, which returns `output`, which is never initialized with anything.

Comment: I get 'undefined' in the console. It's not even outputing a string

Comment: I found the answer to the first part. It wasn't in document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

Hi I created listing for you, review it: [link here new](http://jsfiddle.net/yzd7r1ak/1/)

You have a next issue, you work almost good, you have just one issue: when you return your `output` value it returns it like an value, but if you want to keep connection between `output` and new `apple` variable you should return it like an object in this case it will be returned not like an value but like a link to the object.

Comment: does `output.a = "checked";` do anything if i comment out `console.log("Checked")` nothing gets printed out. so I don't see how the price variable changes outside of the change event. Thanks for your help so far I see that your making a property 'a'. why did you put the alert in setInterval. I need something in a checkbox.

Comment: I changed a link, review it now, there instead of "a" "myPrice" now, put checkbox checked, and you will see updated alert

Comment: why did you use setInterval? if `apple.price.myPrice` works in setInterval How come it doesn't work in the code right after I instantiate apple? That's what  I really want. and the setInterval is very distracting. it locks up the page with an alert. Thanks for your help so for. I will look this over

Comment: Ok you can remove set interval... Ofcours it works, put instead of "alert" "console.log" in setInterval and you will see that it also works. you don't see necessary result because when  you write "console.log(apple.price.myPrice)" variable is still not updated and initialize by "10"(in my code) or like "undefined" (in your code) you can add a "button" for example, instead of setInterval and call "apple.price.myPrice" - and you will see that it still works :)

Comment: I don't understand why it dosnt work on the checkbox im working on and why I would need a set interval or  another element like a button. the value should solely depend on the checkbox.

Comment: Ok, just remove "setInterval"  (it was just for example) and try to use my code in your purpose like you want with check box - and you will see that it will work :)